# Are PHP cookies and 'JS' cookies the same?

Tags: php, javascript, cookies

If i set a cookie in PHP with the setcookie() function, can i access that with javascript cookie api, in other words are the php and javascript cookie access interchangeable?

Comment: [Question 256325](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2562325/javascript-cookies-vs-php-cookies) has another good answer to this question.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

A cookie is a cookie, unless it is specified to be [HTTP only](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/HttpOnly).

Comment: nice, thanks :) I thought they may have been its just I wanted to know 100% before i started doing something!

Comment: except for flash cookies, which can be different

Comment: don't worry, I won't be using flash ;)

Answer (score 3):

Cookies are entirely independent of PHP and Javascript; they're just a *client-side* storage mechanism.  So yes.