# What is the difference between javascript and PHP cookies?

Tags: javascript, php

Hi im new to PHP and Javascript or web development, I was wondering what is the difference between javascript cookies and php cookies.

Comment: A cookie is a cookie. You can get and set these cookies interchangeably, it's just information stored in the browser.

Comment: There isnt any, cookies are stored on the client browser. read this: https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_cookies.asp https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp

Comment: Possible Duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2562325/javascript-cookies-vs-php-cookies

Comment: A cookie is client side (on your browser)
Your php can return a response to the browser with a specific header to tell him to set a specific cookie.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript cookies vs php cookies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2562325/javascript-cookies-vs-php-cookies)

Answer (score 3):

Cookies can be set and read with client side JavaScript or with HTTP response headers (which can be set using any server side programming language including both JavaScript and PHP).

A cookie can be marked as [HttpOnly](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Cookies#Secure_and_HttpOnly_cookies). Such cookies cannot be touched by client side JavaScript. That is the only difference, but it is a difference between client side code and HTTP headers. Language limitations are little more than coincidental.

Answer (score 0):

Both PHP and JavaScript, and indeed all cookies, have the same, or inter-compatible structures! That means that pretty much all cookie-compatible languages can read them.

Cookies tend to hold a set structure, or follow a similar pattern.

- Name - This works in the same way as a variable's name.
- Value - This, again, works in the same way as a variable's value.
- Time/Expiry - This value tells the system when to start rejecting the cookie. This helps to keep systems secure (as user authentication cookies are destroyed after some time and cannot be shared easily/for a long time) and to keep people's hard disks fairly clear!

Take a look at [PHP Cookie documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/features.cookies.php) and compare it to [JavaScript Cookie documentation](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp)! They're basically the same, just written in different languages.